# VSS 6.0 to TFS Migration

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, vssconverter, tfs-migration

Our team is migrating from VSS 6.0 to TFS 2008 to be used for source control purposes. I am wondering if anyone has any experience with this migration. In particular, we are interested in preserving the history of files in source control, as well as any other potential gotchas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy once setup. You will first need to create a usermap.xml. This will map your VSS users to your TFS2008 users. Then you create a project configuration file. I would post examples of mine but I can't get the XML to post.

The project configuration file will point to the usermap XML file. Then all you have to do is type the command "VSSConverter migrate settings.xml" to migrate or "VSSConverter analyze settings.xml" to analyze the project. I suggest you to analze before migrating the project.

Here is a link for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253090(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Do you have VSS 2005 installed? You need it rather than the previous version (6.0d).

Also, do you really need the history in TFS? Or can you draw a line in the sand and say that all history before such and such a date is in VSS and all history after that date is in TFS? If so, you can simply do a get latest from VSS and add the files into TFS. Migrating is non-trivial because you need to deal with VSS users that don't map to domain users, VSS users that don't exist anymore, and although the order of source-control operations is maintained the actual date/time of the operation isn't migrated, it is however stored in the comment as part of the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, when I tried this...

TF60032:  The VSS Converter requires Visual SourceSafe 2005 or later to run.
Please install Visual SourceSafe 2005 or later and try again.